# Rails activerecord-import: How do I know how many records to insert in one batch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I've just started using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import), and it is much faster than the one by one inserts I was doing before. I'm currently inserting in batches of 500 records, and wondered what other people have found to be a good number for the batches? I know there is no "one size fits all" answer. I'm just looking for some guidance by others that have experience with activerecord-import. I've looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/) and Googled it, and haven't found anything.

Additional info fwiw: I'm using Postgres, and saving model objects, not columns and arrays with values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activerecord-import will break the import into groups based on max-allowed-packet for your database adapter, so you shouldn't run into any *problems*.  Optimization is another issue.

The only thing I would be concerned with is the memory allocation - if you've already allocated all the objects and are just feeding them in batches to an `import` call, I'd do them all at once.

If you're generating the objects dynamically for each batch (while reading from file, for example), you should do some testing and see what the memory usage looks like for various batch sizes.

Comment: Hi @klochner. Thanks for the help. I am reading from a file and generating the objects dynamically. I bumped up the batch size from 500 records to 1000, and kept an eye on things and it was still fine. I'll continue to test it out to find the sweet spot. Thanks again.